# Multi column fields layout in vuejs form generator

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, vue-component, vue-directives

Basically Vuejs vue-form-generator generates form layout as single column view having single field per row.

```
<vue-form-generator :schema="schema" :model="model" :options="formOptions"></vue-form-generator>
```

Here is the sample jsfiddle for example:
https://jsfiddle.net/icebob/0mg1v81e/174/

How do we generate multi column view having multiple fields per row using vue-form-generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can add a bootstrap class in object of fields **styleClasses:'col-md-6'**

```
fields: [{
            type: "text",
            label: "ID",
            model: "id",
            readonly: true,
            featured: false,
            disabled: true,
            styleClasses:'col-md-6'
        }]
```

Comment: I have already tried `styleClasses: 'col-md-6'` but no success any other thought?

Comment: @user2423706 you can add your custom class, see an example https://jsfiddle.net/76of8ucs/